# all files such as name, size and type using PHP are clearly correct but the files unable to move to real folder

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-permissions

I am a little bit confuse and have a headache to find the upload file problem. I have the PHP script which is contained a simple code of uploading file. Below is my script:

```
$file_path = "doc_student/";
$image = $final_save_dir . $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'];

if($_FILES['uploadFile']['error'] > 0):
echo "Error: " . $_FILES['uploadFile']['error']. "<br>";
else:
echo "Upload: " .$_FILES['uploadFile']['name'] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " .$_FILES['uploadFile']['type'] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " .($_FILES['uploadFile']['size'] / 1024) . "kb<br>";
echo "Stored in: " .move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], $file_path . $_FILES['uploadFile']['name']) . "<br>";
endif;
```

Everything's worked fine except the file that I upload is not move to the `$file_path = "doc_student/"`.

one of my friend told me to give a proper permission to allow my files upload to the folder as I given below but **how to give a permission in Ubuntu?**

Comment: check the permission on the doc_student directory

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: use `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']["tmp_name"], $file_path)`

Answer (score 0):

use `chown` or `chmod`, `chmod -R 777 doc_sudent` is easy but not safe. `chown -R owner.group doc_sudent`, `owner` and `group` should be the run user and group of php

Comment: is it owner.group is like putting a permission number such as 775 or 777 or else?

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes you are doing in your code.

1. $image = $final_save_dir . $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'];
   should be like this $image = $file_path . basename($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']); which is the filename with the proper path where you want to upload the file.
2. move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], $file_path . $_FILES['uploadFile']['name']) should be like this move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], $image). The second argument of move_uploaded_file should be the filename with the path where you want to upload the file. And this function returns boolean value(either true or false ).

So you may use following method(if you want):
// Check $_FILES['uploadFile']['error'] value.
switch ($_FILES['uploadFile']['error']) {
case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
break;
case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
default:
throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
}

```
// You should also check filesize here.
if ($_FILES['uploadFile']['size'] > 1000000) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
}

$file_path = "doc_student/";
$image = $file_path . basename($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']);

 if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], $image)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
}

echo "File is uploaded successfully.<br>";
echo "Upload: " .$_FILES['uploadFile']['name'] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " .$_FILES['uploadFile']['type'] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " .($_FILES['uploadFile']['size'] / 1024) . "kb<br>";
```

Here is the official reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

For changing the permissions on ubuntu use command `chmod 777 <folder name>`
Change the folder name in the above command to the folder you are uploading with full path.

Comment: ooo.. a big thanks to you Syed Sharique. And I have filtered your code with my style but this is a dummy question from me to ask you. Why you used RuntimeException() by the way? Is it to prevent from hackers attack?

Comment: You are welcome. RuntimeException is an Exception class defined in PHP5. See here http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php. Its just like calling trigger_error() function. Its only purpose is to trigger Error with your custom message, thats all. If its solved your problem, then please be nice to accept it as answer.